# Auto connect to VPN when connected to wifi

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I have selected auto-connect to my VPN for certain wifis. However, what happens is that when it connects to those wifis it brings up the VPN dialog instead of automatically connecting in the background. Under certain conditions this leads to some problems(due to some custom software I have installed). How do I automatically connect to the VPN in the background without the dialog popping up?

Comment: Could you explain how did you manage to acomplish this selective connecting method and what VPN client are you using?

Comment: I go to 'Network Manager' -> 'Edit Connections' -> 'Select a Wifi' -> 'Click on Edit'. On General tab select 'Automatically connect to VPN'